Run website on another url when previous url is not available
We have a website running on Windows IIS with angular, node.js and 3 domains.
When the first domain is not be available, the same website must work on the second domain.
If the second domain isn't available then it must work on third domain.
We need to do it with a text configuration file.
Our main website has one domain for front end and the other for api, but api will be different for second and third domains.

It's not clear what you want. You want the same site accessible using different URLs?

yes, when main domain isnt available for some reasons, it will redirect it to the second url automatically with the same design, and keeping user info

That doesn't make sense. If you have a HA setup there's no reason to use different names. If you don't have a HA setup, it doesn't work either way. DNS is the easiest thing to achieve excellent redundancy and uptime with.

They probably mean when the IP behind domain one is not accessible, use domain two. Sounds like you need to edit your hosts file accordingly.

You have to talk to your network administrators to learn how to define “ when main domain isnt available for some reasons”, either DNS service is down or some other real scenario. Only that leads to meaningful discussions.
